# Which MacBook doesn't have any fans?

Tags: apple-store

I'm looking to buy a MacBook Pro (13"), but I want it to be as quiet as possible.
So, which MacBook Pro doesn't have fan? Only the Gen-5 Broadwell CPU?

Comment: Being Apple products, all MacBooks have large numbers of rabid fans. ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The recently announced 12 inch sized retina screen [MacBook (Early 2015)](http://www.apple.com/macbook/) will be the first fanless MacBook to ship once it goes on sale.

The MacBook Air (11" & 13") and the MacBook Pro 13" have one fan, the MacBook Pro 15" has two.

Comment: thats it, but most of the time you won't hear a thing from those fans

Comment: In the summer with high CPU usage you will definitely hear them.

Comment: i already had a summer with it and it was quite for me. If i want to hear the fans, i just need to start Youtube in Chrome, otherwise its silent.

Comment: Watch a video and you'll hear.

Answer (score 1):

As Matthieu stated the only model without a fan is a new MacBook 12".

The good news is that newest **MacBook Pro Retina (13-inch, Early 2015)** has only one fan which is on only under have load. I'm playing with this machine from few days (max out with i7 CPU) and **most of the time fan is 0 rpm**. (in my 15" model they only slowed down, in 13" is completely off)

You will like new Trackpad as well because in the settings you can make it more quite by setting `Click pressure` to `Light`. So the most loud thing is the keyboard. (but more quite then on the 15" model - less travel keys)

Answer (score 1):

The recently announced MacBook has no fan. All other MacBooks, to my knowledge, have a fan.

Comment: Who downvoted this?  This was a perfectly valid answer.